# What does the '<<=' operator do and what is it called?

Tags: c++

```
  dy <<= 1;
  dx <<= 1;
```

That's some C++ code I found, what does it do to the variables, and what is that operator called?

Comment: Did you not think to look in a book, or a reference website?  (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_operators)

Comment: I am sure this is a duplicate. Can we get it closed as such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That shifts `dy` and `dx` 1 bit to the left.

It's equivalent to (unless dy and dx have operator =<< overloaded)

```
dy = dy << 1;
dx = dx << 1;
```

If `dx` and `dy` are integral types, it's equivalent to multipication by 2.

Note that it is undefined behavior to left-shift a negative number.

This is an ugly hack by programmers who think this is more efficient than just multiplying by 2 (which is not, but it is a lot less readable).

Comment: It's not always a hack.  There are plenty of situations where you really are doing bitwise operations, not arithmetic.  Thus it's natural to use bitwise operators.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I was about to say the same thing. But to be fair, in this case `dy` and `dx` don't sound like names you'd give to a bitfield.

Comment: *It's equivalent to…* depends on the types of `dy` and `dx` and how `operator=`, `operator<<=` and `operator<<` are overloaded for those types.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth agree, I was referring to when it's used to replace multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

This operation is called bit shifting - the binary representation of dy and dx is moved one symbol to the left by adding a zero. Essentially the result is that dx and dy are multiplied by two(unless an overflow happens).

Comment: So doing:
dx *= 2;
dy *= 2;
Will result in the same thing? I want to replace that code, so that most people can understand it.

Comment: if no overflow happens the two statements happen. An overflow will haven if dx * 2 is greater then MAX_INT / 2.

Answer (score 0):

It is the bitshift operator. You shift bits one way or the other with the amount of shifts you specify.

The code you posted means the same as:

`dx = dx << 1`, and `dy = dy << 1`.